# MySql customize Except clause

Tags: mysql

I have table 'Foo' with following format,

```
 ID     Value  
---------------
 1        A  
 2        B  
 3        C  
 4        D  
 5        E
```

Now I would like to query the table  something as,

```
SELECT value FROM Foo WHERE value NOT IN ('A','@','C','#','E','$');
```

So that it would return result as:

```
Values
----------
 @  
 #  
 $
```

And not as

```
Values
----------
 B  
 D
```

Note: I am having more than 30 million records in the table & I will be executing this query continuously on db with different values.

Comment: So your goal is to select `@`, `#` and `$` depending on if they occur in the values column?

Comment: I would like to just show @,#,$ if it does not exists in the table and hide those values which are already there

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted but maybe acceptable:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN '@' NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM foo) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) at,
  (CASE WHEN '#' NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM foo) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) hash,
  (CASE WHEN '$' NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM foo) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) dollar
```

Produces for example this, when there is no `@`, no `$`, and no `#` in foo

```
at   dollar   hash
------------------
0    0        0
```

Comment: it will make things more complex

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table with the values you want to check, and then left join.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tValues (Value VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO tValues (Value) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO tValues (Value) VALUES ('@');
INSERT INTO tValues (Value) VALUES ('C');
--etc

SELECT tValues.* 
FROM
  tValues t
  LEFT JOIN Foo f
  ON
    t.Value = f.Value
WHERE
  f.Value IS NULL
```

Comment: I will have to create temp table each time i query this table, it will be more time consuming

Comment: Creating a temp table is time consuming? Certainly not based on your example, perhaps you should give the exact use-case instead of a very dumbed down example.